# How to test DaggerFragment with FragmentScenario?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-fragmentscenario

I have a simple `Fragment` like so:

```
class SomeFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    ...
}
```

Now I want to test this `Fragment` using `FragmentScenario`

```
class LoginFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        launchFragmentInContainer<SomeFragment>()
        onView(withId(R.id.someButton))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

}
```

But everytime I try to the test its always:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector was found for <...SomeFragment>

How can I properly run the test? Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two ways to solve the problem:

- using a separate build flavor for tests and `typealias`,
- [creating your own `DaggerFragment` and special test variants of your fragments](https://proandroiddev.com/testing-dagger-fragments-with-fragmentscenario-155b6ad18747)

I consider the first approach cleaner and would recommend to use it rather than the latter, but I'll describe both of them, so you can make your own choice.

---

**Build flavors with `typealias`**

1. Create two product flavors, `mock` and `prod`:

`app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        prod
        mock {
            applicationIdSuffix '.mock'
        }
    }
}
```

2. Then set the `typealias` depending on the flavor, let's call it `BaseFragment`:

`prod` flavor,
`app/src/prod/com.example.mypackage/BaseFragment.kt`

```
typealias BaseFragment = DaggerFragment
```

`mock` flavor, `app/src/mock/com.example.mypackage/BaseFragment.kt`

```
typealias BaseFragment = Fragment
```

3. And finally use the `BaseFragment` alias in your fragments:

```
class SomeFragment : BaseFragment() {
   ...
}
```

4. To test the code using `FragmentScenario` switch from the `prod*` build variant to the `mock*` one and set all the dependencies that are supposed to be injected somewhere in your test class (e.g. using mocks)

---

**Own `DaggerFragment` and test variants of the fragments**

1. Create your own `DaggerFragment` (based on the actual `dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment` implementation):

```
abstract class DaggerFragment() : Fragment(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Object>

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        injectMembers()
        super.onAttach(context)

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Object> = androidInjector

    protected open fun injectMembers() = AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
}
```

2. Extend your `DaggerFragment` implementation and **set the fragment `open`**:

```
open class SomeFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    ...
}
```

3. Create another implementation of your fragment for the test purposes and override the `injectMembers` method:

```
class TestSomeFragment : SomeFragment() {

    override injectMembers() {
        /* you can manually inject dependencies and mocks here */
    }
}
```

4. Use `TestSomeFragment` in your tests.

Comment: my only issue with this approach is that now, when you run test at other variants, the test would fail.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Yeah, unfortunately this can be a drawback. However, separating test and production variants of code using product flavors is [recommended by Google developers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html?m=1), so at least it's an officially suggested inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah I kinda agree. I just wish that there is a much better solution than this but I think this is enougn thank you very much :)